# Не работает класс

Tags: input, css

Не могу понять, что не так. Стиль не применяется к `.input_search...`

```
<form action="#">
<input type="text" class="input_search" placeholder="Search the site">
<input type="text" class="input_search_icon">
</form>
```

И вот css:

```
.input_search{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e9ef;
  border-right: none;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding: 11px 0px;
}
.input_search::-webkit-input-placeholder {font:10px "HelveticaNeueLT-Thin";color:#d8dce2;}
.input_search:-moz-placeholder {font:10px "HelveticaNeueLT-Thin";color:#d8dce2;}
.input_search_icon{
  width: 20px;
  margin:0;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  background-image: url(../img/search_icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid #e7e9ef;
  border-left: none;
}
```

[Ссылка на весь проект](http://jsfiddle.net/rp5f4120/).

Вот скрин:

[image]

Comment: И что у вас не работает? http://jsfiddle.net/m3p88dx6/

Comment: Из тех данных, что вы дали, нигде нет ошибки, вот копи-паст вашей инфы: http://jsfiddle.net/5sw5k0pt/ Почему не работает у вас? Либо файл со стилем не подключён на странице, либо стиль перебивается другим стилем с большим весом.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: если ничего не меняеться попробуй подчистить кэш

Comment: Проверьте в другом браузере. Откройте стили в консоли и найдите этот код. Может, его там и нет, и вы что-то не туда сохраняете.

Comment: чистил, на трех браузерах пробовал, перезагрузил бук.осталось винду перебить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в css у вас:

```
.after_top_block:first-child{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;};
```

Убираем `;` и [стили работают](http://jsfiddle.net/rp5f4120/2/)

Comment: вуффф спс, есть какой нибудь валидатор на синтаксис?

Comment: Я использую PhpStorm, после того как ваш класс заработал при перестановке вверх, сразу понял, что где-то выше ошибка, и вставил в программу.